# Are pregnant women allowed to go to temples?

Tags: scripture, temple, women, pregnancy

Is it allowed for pregnant women to go to temples?

If it's not allowed, what are the restrictions?

And are those restrictions based on scriptures or are they just traditions that have been followed for ages?

Comment: Pregnant woman can go upto 5-7 months based on health condition. After 7 months there is restrictions to allowing in to temples, because go to temples there may lot of steps, fire and some-other reasons (like pre-born) effects on baby. Still if they want can do pooja at home.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I will be surprised if one can find direct references to your question in scriptures. At least, there is nothing in the Vedas, Smritis and the Agamas.

So, it remains only to see if the PurAnas and the ItihAsas have something in them  or not.

I am answering your question with an indirect reference, which says, **a woman should be allowed to go to temples till the last month of her pregnancy.**

From Bhairvai Tantram:

> **StrinAm Garbhavatinancha Naivya Dushanam** Na KuryAddasame MAsi KritvA
>   Cha Naraki Bhavet |
>
> ........
>
> There is no prohibition for pregnant women [getting initiated (taking
>   mantra dikshA)] but if taken on the tenth month the woman goes to hell.

So, if a woman is considered pure for the purpose of DikshA (which is the first and foremost among all rituals) for all months of pregnancy except the tenth, then she should be allowed to do any other religious activities like visiting temples, doing daily worship etc in those months.

But, of course, whether she feels like going to temples (because of her health condition) is another important thing to be taken into account.

*NOTe- This is an indirect answer. So you should wait for more direct answers from scriptures.*

Answer (score 2):

Dr. Vaddiparti Padmakar says in *Dharma Sandehalu* program:

> Pregnant women after 5 months should not go to the temples. The reason behind this is health issue.  Many temples used to have steps and are situated on a hill top. If she visits such temples it may effect the health of the mother and baby in the womb. After 5 months, a woman's feet get numb and sometimes they might not be able to walk properly. So, women are not generally not allowed to visit temples due to health problems.
>
> But if the woman is healthy and the temple is very near and if there is no problem in going, then she can visit up to 7 months but should not offer oblations, shouldn't perform circumambulations and other actions which involve physical strain. Other reason is that the temples have powerful yantras under the idol. Adults like us doesn't have negative effect but they are too powerful for babies in the womb. Hence, it is not recommended for pregnant women to visit temples after 5 months. They should not visit temples after 7 months.
>
> But there is no restrictions to do simple poojas and listen to religious discourses and purana stories in their home itself.

He says it is said in Shukra Niti that a pregnant woman is not allowed after 7 months and in Brihaspati smriti it is said that a pregnant woman is not allowed after 5 months.

Source: [This](https://youtu.be/kd6wRe32a6c) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-UykXQX6U28) video in Telugu.

Comment: You should post this as a comment. It's not a perfect answer that's why I mentioned on comments.

Comment: @CR241 Why it's not a perfect answer? There is a source and explanation. Actually it is vice versa. Answering should not be done in the comments. Words of scholars are also valid sources. Random blogs are not valid.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I prefer the religious recommendation. Not the scientific once.

Comment: @sugunan The answer was given in a religious talk show on a religious channel. This is not scientific. But the reason behind this restrictions are 1. Health issues and 2.Dangerous effect on the child in the womb. The yantras in the temple are too powerful for the child. The orator it is said in Shukra niti and Brihaspati smriti.  But I don't have those scriptures. Brihaspati smriti is now defunct.

Comment: I have read the Brihaspati Smriti. There is nothing in it. Also what is Sukra Niti? There is a Smriti attributed to Sukra called the Usana Smriti. Is that the one?

Comment: @Rickross Yes, that might be the one. It might be Shukra smriti. But there is a text called Shukra neeti/s,smriti which was the canonical text for Rakshasas. I found Sanskrit text of Brihaspati smriti too. There's nothing in it. But it is only 9 or 10 pages. Is Brihaspati smriti a smriti with less verses?

Comment: @SreeCharan In your answer is more about talk show Q&A session. Don't say they are scholars, if yes provide trustable source not like regional show videos. How can you say that? Most Bloggers also type of scholars who provide info from multiple sources.

Comment: @CR241 There is huge difference between a blog and these people. The orator in the show I provided is a scholar in Puranas and itihasas. He is well known in the Telugu states. He is a Tribhasha sahasravadhani.The source is  trustworthy.They are not opinions of the person. They give reasons from the scriptures only. Blogging is different they give their mere opinions like God's fav. food, colour, famous folklores  and say it is from Mahabharata etc., The show I provided is trustworthy. It addresses the question. Who says show videos are not trustworthy? Check the valid sources from our meta.

Comment: @CR241 [Which scriptures / sources are considered valid?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/806/which-scriptures-sources-are-considered-valid) and [What kind of references are valid in answers? Are modern works allowed?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/596/what-kind-of-references-are-valid-in-answers-are-modern-works-allowed)

Comment: @SreeCharan while answering does he mention source from Puranas, no? Thanks for sharing valid source list. Here we are going different way which is not helpful to find out the answer. I'm from Telugu state and never heard about him, it doesn't mean I know all (it's based on person interest). My main concern was your way of presenting/influencing answer

Comment: @SreeCharan Yes Brihaspati Smriti is a small text. And no Usana Smriti (attributed to Usanas or Sukra) is not only a text to be followed by the Asuras. Its one of the 18 Smritis mentioned in the Yajnvalkya Smriti's list. So, it is as important for us as the other 17 Smritis. And BTW even the Usana Smriti does not have any info on this. No info is found in Smritis , Vedas or Agamas as i have mentioned in the answer itself.

Comment: **Pregnant women after 5 months should not go to the temples. The reason behind this is health issue** Also its highly unlikely that a Smriti will cite that as reasons for prohibitions..@SreeCharan

Comment: @Rickross Yes, Smritis do not mention reasons. The reason was given by the orator. That's why put it it in the block quotes. The orator said Brihaspati and Shukra said likewise. I don't know from where they mentioned. Not sure about it. Yes, Shukra smriti is a smriti for all the people. But it says in a verse, we can take back our words and lie. There are some verses which are more applicable to the Asuras than human beings. :D Having said that, I don't demean Shukracharya. He is equal to Brihaspati in splendour and knowledge.